# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is read-only and so may not be used for actions

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

n my page there are lots of drop down boxes and text fields.while testing the page in eclipse  IDE its showing the above exception. I am not able to find any solution for this Exception

This is my code:

```
public class QuoteNewEntry {
private WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
baseUrl = "http:///";
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testQuoteNewEntry() throws Exception {
driver.get(baseUrl + "");
System.out.println("The current Url: "+ driver.getCurrentUrl());
assertEquals("", driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.id("RdbtnLight")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("tom");
driver.findElement(By.id("txtpassword")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("txtpassword")).sendKeys("tom");
driver.findElement(By.id("btnSubmit")).click();
assertEquals("", driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.id("btnTrade")).click();
System.out.println("The current Url: "+ driver.getCurrentUrl());
assertEquals("", driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.id("btnQuote")).click();
System.out.println("The current Url: "+ driver.getCurrentUrl());
assertEquals("Quote", driver.getTitle());
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNew")).click();
System.out.println("The current Url: "+ driver.getCurrentUrl());

new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlLineOfBus"))).selectByVisibleText("FCL");

driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCaptured")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtCaptured")).sendKeys("3");

driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_rbtn3rdParty")).click();

Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTotalTransitDays")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTotalTransitDays")).sendKeys("10");

driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtVoyageFrequency")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtVoyageFrequency")).sendKeys("weekly");
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtExternal")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtExternal")).sendKeys("ex");
Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.id("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSave")).click();
try{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value = 'alert']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
     catch(WebDriverException we){
     }
 }

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
//driver.quit();
String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
  fail(verificationErrorString);
}
}

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
try {
  driver.findElement(by);
  return true;
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  return false;
}
}

private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
try {
  Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
  if (acceptNextAlert) {
    alert.accept();
  } else {
    alert.dismiss();
  }
  return alert.getText();
} finally {
  acceptNextAlert = true;
}
}
}
```

Comment: can you post some of your code or HTML code, so that we can investigate

Answer (score 1):

The exception suggests your are trying to perform an edit action on an element that is read-only. This includes actions such as `SendKeys()` and `Click()`. You can either make these elements writable in your application, or you must check if they are read-only prior to accessing them; if they are you cannot perform the action.

Comment: Actually there is one page.And then In edit mode m trying to enter some data and then save that page.Im edit mode i want to test that page.but its showing the above exception.

Comment: Do you go from a 'view' mode to a 'edit' mode? It could be that the element becomes available after a short pause when switching to edit mode. This could cause the exception as well.

Comment: ya from view mode to edit mode.what to do?shall i use Thread sleep? or is there anything else?

Comment: You would be better off using a WebDriverWait, or setting an implicit wait timeout. Though, yes, a sleep would work if it is long enough. I would give an example but i'm stuck on my phone atm.